# Getting size of s3 directory in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a s3 path in dataframe columns for which I need the size of directory.
Is there is any way in spark scala by which we can get the size of s3 directory in a new column.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spark scala, but you would need to sum the size of every object stored in that given path. There is no S3 command to find the size of a 'directory'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this udf to get the size of s3 bucket.

```
    val sizeEstimator = udf { (path: String) =>
          val path1 = new Path(path)
          val hdfs = path1.getFileSystem(new Configuration())
          var length:Long =0
          if (hdfs.exists(path1)) {
            val cSummary = hdfs.getContentSummary(path1)
            length = cSummary.getLength
          }
          length
        }
    
    
val size =df.select(udfService.sizeEstimator(lit("<Path to s3>"))).first().get(0).asInstanceOf[Long]
```